# How to get specific files from amazon S3 bucket into snowflake stage table

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Every day files are pushing into Amazon S3 bucket, I have to get specific day files to perform day level aggregation in table.
I have to avoid getting all files from S3 bucket.

sample file names:

sales:abc:**2020:02:22**_01:15:04.csv
sales:abc:**2020:01:30**_01:21:04.csv
sales:abc:**2020:01:30**_01:51:04.csv
sales:abc:**2020:01:30**_01:23:04.csv

I have completed setup for S3 bucket and could read data by using below query, but I should pass the file name date part as dynamic to get day level files.

```
select
$1 as timestamp,
$3 as unitssold,
$4 as rate
from  @s3_realtime/sales:abc:2020:01:30_01:21:04.csv
```

Could some one help me in this.

Comment: Are you asking how to only load the files that have recently landed in s3 but haven't yet been loaded into Snowflake? Did you have a look at using Snowpipe for this? It's exactly what you're looking for I think

Comment: Are you trying to only load a particular file or only files that haven't been loaded before?  If every file gets loaded and you are just trying to avoid loading a file more than once, then Snowflake handles that for you.  It will not reload a file that has already been loaded unless you FORCE it to.